# Different versions of random dynamical systems

Tags: probability-theory, dynamical-systems

Consider the two following versions of a random dynamical system:

$\mathbf{1.}:$ Let  $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, \sigma)$ be a probability preserving dynamical system. Let $T_{\omega}: X \rightarrow X , \omega \in \Omega$ be a family of maps on some compcat metric space $(X, d).$ The random dynamical system is then created by looking at the composition
$$T^n_{\omega} (x) = T_{\sigma ^{n-1} \omega} \ \circ ... \circ \ T_{\omega} (x)$$
for a point $x \in X,$ with the corresponding skew product
$$T(\omega, x) = (\sigma \omega, T_{\omega} (x)).$$

$\mathbf{2.}:$ Let  $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}, \sigma)$ be a probability preserving dynamical system. For each $x \in X$, let $X_{\omega} \subset X$ be a subset of a compact metric space $(X, d).$ Let $T_{\omega} : X_{\omega} \rightarrow X_{\sigma \omega}$ be a transformation. The random dynamical system is then created on the bundle
$$\mathcal{E} = \bigsqcup_{\omega \in \Omega} \omega \times X_{\omega}$$
with the skew product $S: \mathcal{E} \rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ and
$$S(\omega, x) = (\sigma \omega, T_{\omega}(x)).$$ Similarly,
$$T^n_{\omega} (x) = T_{\sigma ^{n-1} \omega} \ \circ ... \circ \ T_{\omega} (x).$$

Are these random dynamical systems doing the same thing? In other words, are these equivalent? I am not totally sure what the second system is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly the constructions are the same if $X_\omega=X$ for all $\omega$, right?

It may be helpful to note that this is a very common construction that all of us should be used to. Namely, let $f\colon M\to M$ be a diffeomorphism of a smooth manifold $M$. Then each derivative $d_xf\colon T_xM \to T_{f(x)}M$ takes a tangent space $T_xM$ to another tangent space $T_{f(x)}M$. This is somewhat awkward to work with since the tangent spaces vary.

The "solution" can be to define a map $F\colon TM\to TM$ (usually called extension, cocycle, etc) by
$$
F(x,v)=(f(x),d_xfv)
$$
for $(x,v)\in M\times T_x M$.
Notice the similarity to your map $S\colon \mathcal{E} \to\mathcal{E}$ defined by
$$S
(\omega, x) = (\sigma (\omega), T_{\omega}(x))
$$
for $(\omega,x)\in \Omega\times X_\omega$, where $X_\omega$ corresponds to $T_xM$.

In many situations we are able to identify (sometimes unavoidably using charts) all tangent spaces $T_xM$ with some fixed $\mathbb R^k$ where $k$ is the dimension of the manifold. The same may occur in your setting, depending on what is $X_\omega$ after all, which one may be able to identity, or not, with a single set $X$ *in some precise manner*.

This gives the answer to your question: sometimes they are equivalent, sometimes they are not.

I should also add that both constructions are very particular cases of a general construction obtained from a group action, in your case a measurable group action (which means that the map on the first component preserves the measure). Note that measurable vector bundles need not have all fibers of the same dimension.

Comment: Thank you. So, the cocyle, or the skew product, is assumed to be measurable. I am just assuming in my case that that means $\mathcal{F} \otimes \mathcal{B}-$ measurable, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the Borel sigma algebra on $X$?

Comment: @MathIsLife12 It depends. Sometimes we just assume that it is an extension of a measurable map on the base, that is, of $\sigma$, without further topological or measurable properties. So, it really depends on your particular situation, but since you you have a compact metric space indeed you can think of that $\sigma$-algebra (or better of a $\sigma$-algebra induced on the sets $X_\omega$).